# Finding the right tools for programming a futuristic-styled UI project

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, 2d

I've always been inspired by dynamic, futuristic-like user interfaces. The best I can describe is a graphic interface such as in the latest Iron Man movies.

Although I wouldn't build a full blown application, I would like to make little snipplets of animations that I plan to make interactive. And maybe put them together someday to make something bigger. Admittedly, I will use for audio manipulation in the future but anyway, that's not the point since it's the animations/graphics I'm unsure of.

I know it's possible to make those kind of animations in Adobe After Effects. I'm just having a hard time thinking of the processes (artistically and programmability) to proceed.

While researching on this on my own I have acquired basic experience with OGRE 3D and Blender. I've imported and compiled meshes on OGRE, have been able to do basic things like move the meshes around which is about it.

I'm beginning to think I may be approaching this the wrong way and there are better tools or if 3D is overkill for those kind of animations when 2D would suffice and maybe provide a smoother experience.

I'm having trouble understanding the process and am wondering two things:

1.)The main thing I'm having trouble understanding is how to get still graphics to make animations? Do the meshes keep the timeline from a program like Blender then a graphics engine like OGRE reads the timeline and plays them?

**Most importantly:**

2.)Do I even need graphics (meshes)? Most of the interface are thin-border boxes, text and shapes of transparent LED-like colors that can move around dynamically to make that futuristic effect.

Please share your opinions, suggestions and anything you think might help me accomplish to develop those kinds of sexy eye candy! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you look at awesome futuristic UIs in movies, they are usually made of

- basic primitives
- desaturated colors, and/or one color tone
- transparency
- a cool font or two
- high-tech text, graphs or similar
- simple animations to make things look "alive", blinking lights/text and similar
- a touch interface, of course

Maybe you can't do a lot about the touch interface, but the rest is really not hard graphics wise, it's a matter of carefully crafted artwork and combining simple elements in a cool way.

Also I would look into Adobe Photoshop and fancy texturing rather than Blender and fancy modelling, as you are looking for a fancy 2D UI, and detailed 3D models will not be that important. Playing around in photoshop (well, or GIMP if you want a free alternative) can help you develop your art skills, and help you get that high-tech, sci-fi look on a 2D surface.

You know, I would go as far as to suggest making some sci-fi wallpapers in the style you are after before trying to solve this problem in code. I think you will find that photo manipulation skills and an eye for art will help you here. And for gods sake, look at those movies (Iron Man, Minority Report etc.) that have those UIs you are aiming at, and analyze what exactly they are. Decompose them like I did in the list above.

As for the "which tools should I use?", I say the answer to that is fairly simple:

- OpenGL
- Photoshop (or GIMP if you are a starving student etc.)
- A compiler & toolchain
- A code editor/IDE
- A cup

I see this is tagged C++, which is an excellent choice of programming language if I may say so.

Ogre is a full blown 3D engine, which is fine, but not exactly targeted at what you want to use it for. You might find that you struggle to get what you want done (disclaimer: I have not tried this in Ogre, and it might work well for this. Then again, when did you last see Ogre used in an audio manipulation program?). My advice is to learn good, simple OpenGL. That would give you complete power over your UI, not get in your way or limit you in any way. It is also cross platform, well documented, and used by tons of developers all over the world (also for audio manipulation applications). I can't see how you could possibly go wrong with it. The fun part is that it probably won't take you long to get advanced enough in it to start developing some pretty nice UIs. As I mentioned, it's more of an art problem than a coding problem.

The cup is for the coffee, by the way. :)

Comment: OGRE for an audio manipulation program will work as the visual part of it, the sound engine will be done separately and will be tied with the graphic part of the program. You have some great suggestions thank you for that. But it would answer my questions completely if you could tell me a little bit about the animation process? Do the meshes contain the timeline animation and then the timeline events are played by the 3D rendering engine (OGRE)? If I used something like photoshop for the graphics, would I still have to import them to Blender convert them to meshes and then import them to OGRE?

Comment: For the parts when you won't simply use basic draw functions (don't know if OGRE even have these), you will probably make a basic mesh and apply your photoshop art to it as a texture. For animation, I was imagining more of a manual approach - i.e. that you code the animations from scratch in C++, not in Blender, since these are quite basic animations we are talking about. Again, I do not know how OGRE would handle that.

Comment: ... cont: If you want to use Blender's animation facilities, I think you might have to write your own file format & exporter, since (IIRC) Blender really doesn't support a lot of common file formats at the moment. It *does* however have decent capabilities when it comes to writing your own exporter, and you will find that many others have done similar things. You'd have to look that up, though. I have no idea if OGRE has any special animation support. If you were using OpenGL you would probably make your own animation renderer, using the file format you created for Blender.

Comment: ...cont: I do not know if you can do similar things with OGRE, maybe you can, or maybe OGRE has built-in functionality that requires a special format. Basically, if you want to use OGRE I can not really help you further

Comment: I've had some time to think about it and to be honest I wanted to make a UI similar to that of what shows on his monitors. Which I think is all 2D. If you don't know much about OGRE, what other libraries do you know that you could tell me how the process works?

Comment: Well, I would go with pure OpenGL, as I said, and that is what I know. For the animations you are looking at, I think you should be able to easily hardcode them. No need to mess with animations in blender at all. I think that would be the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most efficient way is to keep track of all your graphics data (meshes, animations, effects) in "media files" and load & play them in runtime. Though you'll be able to easily change your game without changing the code.

For example, you have a Diablo-like game and you wanna turn it to the future-style. You just need to rewrite some player and AI scripts and modify meshes/effects/sounds/animations. But if you've done those via code - it will be a new game from scratch.

Comment: Not really the answer I'm looking for, but thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Ogre, but you already used that, so by my opinion, you are on the right track.

Look up 'billboards' in Ogre documentation, re: LED and 2D stuff.